# can't change constraint.constant programmatically in viewDidLoad:

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I am using autolayout and storyboards. I try to change the constraint in viewDidLoad: so that it takes into account different device models. The constraint is successfully connected as IBOutlet.

In viewDidLoad: I change the constraint like this:

```
   self.containerConstraint.constant = 250
```

I DO NOT want to animate the constraint (I later animate it and it works fine). I only want to it to set the view that is constraining to the right spot when the viewController appears. This usually works, however in this case, it persist to use the value determined in storyboard. This is how constraint looks:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: trying setting `self.containerConstraint.constant = 250` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  You should also think about how you can use layout constraints to your benefit to avoid setting the constants on a per device basis.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is to early.

Comment: Krompir2 ... dasdom is sort of correct on this, unfortunately, not unforutnate because of dasdom, but unfortunate because of when the view is actually "set" with actual "frames" and values in the viewcontroller lifecycle. Here's the breakdown: with autolayout, there's ZERO values set for frames in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear, these values arent' set with autolayout until ViewDidLayoutSubviews or ViewDidAppear. You can check this with NSLog on the views that use AutoLayout. check NSStringFromCGrect(someView.frame). Logging this in ViewdidLoad or Viewwillappear will return {0,0}{0,0}

Comment: So, what I'm saying is try to set the constraint in ViewDidLayOutSubviews or ViewDidAppear.

Comment: so far, I have set all but one constraint in viewDidLoad. It worked great excpet for the one I am asking here. Now I shipped constrain.constant code to viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewDidLoad and none of the constraints is working as it should. very bizare

Comment: Setting the constant in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear` worked for me. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See that `wR hR` option under `Constant`? That was the problem. Looks like constraints that use size classes cant be set in viewDidLoad.